# Identity comparison of generics in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm wondering if and how I could do identity comparison of instances of a generic class. For example:

```
class Foo<T> {
  let a: T
  let b: T

  init(a: T, b: T) {
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
  }

  func isIdentical() -> Bool {
    return a === b
  }
}
```

Doing something like that is giving me an error at compile-time:

> Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to two T operands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should works:

```
class Foo<T: AnyObject> {
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^ ADDED
    let a: T
    let b: T

    init(a: T, b: T) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }

    func isIdentical() -> Bool {
        return a === b
    }
}
```

You need `<T: AnyObject>` to ensure the `T` is a `class`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend limiting the generic's type to the Comparable protocol.

```
class Foo<T: Comparable> {...}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm specifically trying to test for identity, not equality. `==` via Comparable or Equatable can only test for equality.

Answer (score 0):

Identity check is only for AnyObject types and not for all types. I think in Swift you could not have identity check for basic data types like Int as it does not conform to AnyObject.

As Type T in generic type Foo is not known to be confirming to AnyObject identity check could not be applied. You could place generic restriction to make it work like this:

```
class Foo<T: AnyObject> {
    let a: T
    let b: T

    init(a: T, b: T) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }

    func isIdentical() -> Bool {
        return a === b
    }
}

class SomeClass {

}


var so = SomeClass()
var a = Foo<SomeClass>(a: SomeClass(), b: SomeClass())
var b = Foo<SomeClass>(a: so, b: so)

println(a.isIdentical())    //False
println(b.isIdentical())    //True
```